# List item not displaying using components within components concept in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My code is not working. I want to print my tasks in lists but no list item displaying now. https://prnt.sc/pd6yx5
I want to display like this https://prnt.sc/pd6zoe
I want components within components concept

HTML:

```
<div class="childcomponents-wrap">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div id="childtasks"> 
                    <h2>Vue Components within Components</h2>
                    <task-list></task-list>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS(Vue.js):

```
Vue.component('task-list', {
    template:
        '<div>
            <task v-for="task in tasks">{{ task.task }}</task>
        </div>',

    data(){
        return {
            tasks: [
                {task: 'Go to the United States', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Kerala', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Tamil Nadu', complete: false},
                {task: 'Go to Simla', complete: true}
            ]
        };
    }
});

Vue.component('task', {
    template: '<li><slot></slot></li>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#childtasks'
});
```

Comment: It's working as expected. Check here https://codepen.io/lucifer7557/pen/YzKoLNo

Comment: Thanks @Lucifer, Now the code is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this like so:

**The Component Structure:**

```
Vue.component('task-list', {
    template: 
        `<div>
            <li v-for="task in tasks">{{ task.task }}</li>
        </div>`,
    data(){
        return {
            tasks: [
                {task: 'Go to the United States', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Kerala', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Tamil Nadu', complete: false},
                {task: 'Go to Simla', complete: true}
            ]
        };
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#childtasks',
});
```

**Calling the component:**

```
<div id="childtasks">
  <task-list></task-list>
</div>
```

Check this **[working code sample](https://jsbin.com/qosuconeqo/edit?html,output)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by sending `tasks` as props from `task component` and render tasks prop. Hope it will help.

```js
Vue.component('task-list', {

    template:
    '<div>
        <task :tasks="tasks"></task>
    </div>',

        data(){

            return {

                tasks: [

                {task: 'Go to the United States', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Kerala', complete: true},
                {task: 'Go to Tamil Nadu', complete: false},
                {task: 'Go to Simla', complete: true}

                ]
            };
        }
    });

    Vue.component('task', {     
    props: ['tasks'],
    template: '<li v-for="task in tasks"><slot>{{task.task}}</slot></li>'

    });

    new Vue({

        el: '#childtasks'

    });
```